# How to get bootstrap first column second row content to align with second column bottom line?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here's what I want:

```
+-row3----------++-row9----------+    
|                | |         |  
|        | |
|                | |Image   
+----------------+ |            
+-row3----------+  |
|                | |
| Need content   | |
| bottom align   | |
|  here          | |
|                | |                |
+----------------+ +----------------+
-----------------------------------------------
```

My HTML as below:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
        bootstrap table css - html table
        bootstrap table css - html table
        </div>
            <div class="row">
        bootstrap table ----- Need this table to show at bottom align with same div as shown on beside column.
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        The image is shown here - vertically large height than the first column.

    </div>
</div>
```

As per sketch, need content to align bottom. tried - vertical-align:bottom but its not aligning.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. Can you explain.

Comment: put each row in separate `row` div and use the same `col-whatever`  (in each row) to align the columns

Comment: already added row but, issue with bottom align. it looks same as fiddler.

Comment: please add a sketch to make clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: added more details exact sketch.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if it helps. Expand the snippet to go full screen. You can achieve the height of the image by setting the `height` property to the `div class="col-md-9"`.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-3" style="">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: blue;">

            bootstrap table css - html table
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: red;">

            bootstrap table css - html table
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9" style="background-color: green; height:40px;">
        Image shown here - vertically large height then first column.

      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: actually, Image is second column for same row.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, added `div` with height styles, it adds gape and close to bottom. `<div style="height:200px;"></div>`

Thanks